# OpenCV - How to properly call bm3dDenoising()?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I would like to run a small OpenCV script in **BM3D denoising filter**.

I can't properly call this function in OpenCV.

`bm3dDenoising()`?

Could anyone help me please? About `include` and `namespace`?

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/photo/photo.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv::xphoto;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Load an Image
    Mat img = imread("C:\\image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Image", img);


    //Blur Effect
    GaussianBlur(img, img, cv::Size(3, 3), 0);
    cv::xphoto::bm3dDenoising(img, img);  // ???? 

    namedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Output", img);

    //Wait Key press
    cvWaitKey(0);

    //destroy
    cvDestroyWindow("Image");
    cvDestroyWindow("BlurEffect");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing OpenCV extra modules, i.e. opencv_contrib: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Once you get your development environment ready, you can take a look at the sample code:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xphoto/test/test_denoise_bm3d.cpp

Answer (score 0):

What are your errors? If it is error: ‘cv::xphoto’ has not been declared is a compilation error, not a linker error. Probably, your compiler is not able to look for definitions of cv::xphoto.

Try to give explicit path. #include "path/opencv2/.....h"

or provide the include path in -I switch.

g++ -I *.cpp -l  -o

I hope it will help.